# prove that trace(A*A) = trace (B*B)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be unitary equivalent $n\times n$ matrices. Prove that $\text{trace}(A^*A) = \text{trace}(B^*B)$.

I'm not sure where to begin this proof.

Comment: $AA$ and $BB$ are also equivalent. Do you have the result for equivalent matrices?

Comment: I know that it means A=UBU* and B=UAU*

Comment: Yes. (Well actually other one should be otherway around.) But you also have $AA = UBU^* UBU^* = UBBU^*$ so $AA$ and $BB$ are also similar.

Comment: There is a result that says similar matrices have the same trace. This is proved by first noticing (calculating from the formula) that tr(ABC) = tr(CAB) for any matrices A, B and C.

Comment: By the way, notice that "tr(ABC) = tr(CAB)" only holds for cyclic permutation of the matrices, not (in general) for all permutations.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\text{trace}(A^*A) &= \text{trace}((UBU^*)^*(UBU^*)) = \text{trace}(UB^*U^*(UBU^*)) = \text{trace}(UB^*U^*UBU^*)\\
&=\text{trace}(UB^*BU^*) = \text{trace}(U(B^*BU^*))= \text{trace}(B^*BU^*U) \\
&= \text{trace}(B^*B)
\end{align}

The last step uses the fact that $\text{trace}(AB)= \text{trace}(BA)$.